# Do concurrent Field Value Increments with Batched Writes cause batch to fail

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If you have two batches run at the same time, both containing an update to the database that increments a value in the same document through firestore.fieldvalue.increment(), will the increments fail because they are writing to the same document at same time? If so, will that mean that both batches will fail altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be no failure.  The code will work exactly as you expect, and each increment will work correctly.  Each increment is executed in its own miniature transaction that preserves consistency among other increments on that field.